# Merging objects

Tags: 3d-printing

I’m trying to create a nose for a toy figure I’m working on but I can’t figure out how to move objects in front of each other in order to merge them? Like when I create a new shape it appears either behind my first shape or inside it? Any help?

Comment: You can change the position of the 3D cursor by holding Shift and right clicking. When you add a new object it will appear at the position of the 3D cursor. Place the cursor where you want the new object to appear.

Comment: Can you edit your post? Title is about Merging objects, description about how to place objects. Screenshot would be helpful. You aim to this technique  - merging silhouettes cuts into object? https://www.comsol.com/blogs/modeling-irregular-shapes-how-to-import-curve-data-and-loft-a-solid/ or here http://www.colacola.se/wip_p47_model.htm